# Setup decimal precision on phx.gen.schema Ecto migration

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

How do setup decimal precision on ecto migrations?

When I run:

`$ mix phx.gen.schema Coin coins ticker:string:unique name:string price:decimal`

I'd like to create a table with `decimal(20,10)` precision. By default, the precision is `decimal(10,0)`

Answer (score 4):

Here are all the available options of [`mix phx.gen.schema`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Mix.Tasks.Phx.Gen.Schema.html). The generator doesn't seem to support such settings.

You can find the migration in `/priv/repo/migrations`, there you can change:

```
add :price, :decimal, precision: 20, scale: 10
```

Under the hood ecto is using [Decimal](https://hexdocs.pm/decimal/readme.html) library.